# Macbook is wobbly, creaks when pressed at the bottom

Tags: mac, hardware, repair

My macbook air M1 is wobbly on the bottom right. I can get it to level out by pressing down, but it will always float back up. It also creaks occasionally, and when pressing on the bottom plate middle right theres a loud noise (the bottom plate is touching the interior). I have the suspicion that the bottom is warped. Can I somehow fix this at home? I've reinserted the bottom panel multiple times, loosened and tightened the screws, but the macbook eventually reverts to its wobbly state. Need help

Comment: If it is bent you could "fix" it at home by bending it back, but that is obviously something that should be considered with caution. Before you take any steps you should definitively confirm that it's not the battery that is swelling that's causing the MacBook to wobble (either yourself if you feel technically savvy enough or at a service provider).

Comment: This Mac is less than 1 year old. If you are confident that you haven't dropped it, or otherwise damaged it, you should take it back to the shop. Don't manually repair something that is still under warranty.